# Extracting subset of string In R

Tags: r

I have a column in excel sheet containing information like this in every row "NF2:NM_181830:exon5:c.401_402insCGGTGTGAACT:p.Y138Sfs*3,NF2:NM_181831:exon5:c.401_402insCGGTGTGAACT:p.Y138Sfs*3,NF2:NM_181828:exon6:c.524_525insCGGTGTGAACT:p.Y179Sfs*3"

Now I only want to extract "exon5, exon6" from each row in the column. Is it possible to do in R?

Thank you

Comment: Easy: `stringr::str_extract_all(x, "exon\\d")`. Base R: `gregexpr("exon\\d", x) |> regmatches(x, m = _)`. If you want only one `"exon5"` per row apply `unique` after extracting all of them.

Comment: hi.... thank you very ,much, it partially worked but I need a column next to each row showing exon information. Can I do that?

Comment: @RuiBarradas if you want only one `exon5` use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`

Comment: Please elaborate on *exon information*. How many? `data$info2 <- length(gregexpr("exon\\d", data$info)[[1L]])`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, you are right. But I assumed the OP also wants `exon6` so `gregexpr` must be used.